# Should I use static nested classes to represent abilities in a game?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, composition

I am making a card game in which a variety of cards have access to statically defined abilities. I see no need to make the abilities directly instantiable objects since all of their fields and methods are distinct. My question is would it be a good idea to use static nested classes to represent these abilities, or perhaps is there a more effective alternative?

```
class Ability {
...
    static class Strike {
    ...
    }

    static class Detonate {
    ...
    }

    static class Dodge {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Is `Strike` an `Ability`?

Comment: "more effective" doesn't mean anything. It's hard to tell you what the right design is without any context. (Like, say, how and where will `Ability` and `Strike` et al. be used?)

Comment: That said my take is this doesn't matter. Trying to hide every single class that's not part of an API surface seems as excessive pedanticism to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should extend the `Ability` class, in separate `.java` files.

```
public class Strike extends Ability
{ ... }
public class Detonate extends Ability
{ ... }
public class Dodge extends Ability
{ ... }
```

What Abilities have in common should be placed in the `Ability` class.

Answer (score 1):

SotiriosDelimanolis's comment should give you a hint "strike **IS** An Ability" not that "ability **HAS A** strike"